# Securely read a file in java

Tags: java, java-security

I am scanning my code with IBM AppScan, and in one method I am passing file uploaded by user of `UploadedFile` type and reading it to a byte array using below code. But the scan gives a "Vulnerability Type - Validation.Required" error. I am verifying the file extension and `null` checking the file before I run this piece of code.

Validation check:

```
if (file != null && !file.getFileName().isEmpty()) {
     // Checking file extension here. Like jpg,png etc.
}
```

It falls in category **CWE 20** if it helps.
https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/20.html

```
private int fileUpload(UploadedFile file) { // import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;
        try {
            String fileName = file.getFileName();
            int fileSize = (int) file.getSize();
            String fileType = new Validator().fetchFileExtension(fileName);
            byte[] filebytea = new byte[fileSize];
            try {
                FileInputStream fileStream = (FileInputStream) file.getInputstream();
                fileStream.read(filebytea); // Error: Vulnerability Type Validation.Required
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //System.out.println("error in file stream" + e.getMessage());
            }
```

Comment: Can you format your code correctly so it looks like code and also post how your doing your validation

Comment: Where and how is `bFile` defined?

Comment: Try not casting to `FileInputStream`. Just use `try (InputStream inputStream = uploadFile.getInputstream()) { inputStream.read(bFile); }`

Comment: Better yet, use [`getContents()`](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/6.1/org/primefaces/model/UploadedFile.html#getContents--), as in: `byte[] bFile = uploadFile.getContents();`

Comment: I have updatde the code please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `read` is the problem. It can but does not have to read the data fully. Hence you have to check the return value of read and call it multiple times. If you don't want to implement this yourself you can use `DataInputStream.readFully()` instead or `fileStream.readAllBytes()` (the latter requires Java 9+).

The following code should not cause any problems and works on Java 7+:

```
    try (DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(file.getInputstream())) {
        in.readFully(filebytea); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //System.out.println("error in file stream" + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Or use [`byte[] filebytea = file.getContents();`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58657176/securely-read-a-file-in-java/58657591#comment103619548_58657176)

Comment: byte[] filebytea = file.getContents(); This worked. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use FileInputStream or FileOutputStream. They are considered as harmful. In some cases rhey can lead to GC problems which you don't want in production.

See [this](https://dzone.com/articles/fileinputstream-fileoutputstream-considered-harmful) explanation. SonarQube typically shows this issue as well.

Instead you should use:

```
Files.newInputStream(..)
Files.newOutputStream(..)
```

Comment: OP is using a 3rd-party library which happens to return a `FileInputStream`, so unless you're suggesting for OP to replace their UI framework to something other than [PrimeFaces](https://www.primefaces.org/), and it doesn't appear that you are suggesting that, this answer is *useless*, as the use of `FileInputStream` is not under OPs control. --- Now, why OP felt the need to cast to `FileInputStream`, and not just use the `InputStream` defined as the return type of `getInputstream()`, is unknown, but that doesn't change the usefulness of this answer, which is: **Not useful**.